# Jackson exception: Could not resolve type id as a subtype of

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to parse following JSON string with one field inside. Unfortunatelly still getting exception:

```
InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'pin' as a subtype of `com.example.dto.AuthorizationRequest`: known type ids = [AuthorizationRequest]
```

Here is base class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT ,use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AuthorizationRequest.class, name = "AuthorizationRequest")})
public interface IMessage {}
```

Derived class:

```
public class AuthorizationRequest implements IMessage {

    @JsonProperty( value = "pin", required = true )
    private String pin;

    public String getPin() {
        return pin;
    }

    public void setPin(String pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
    void test(){
        String request =
                "{\n"
                + "  \"AuthorizationRequest\": {\n"
                + "             \"pin\": \"1234\"\n"
                + "  }\n"
                + "}";

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);

        AuthorizationRequest authorizationRequest = null;
        try {
            authorizationRequest = objectMapper.readValue(request, AuthorizationRequest.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? I need to use request name as json root element.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete `objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true)` line. The error is due to the fact that the line unwraps the initial object so escalating of one level at the intern of the json file obtaining the `{"pin" : "1234"}` json with the `""AuthorizationRequest"` label. The `JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT` annotation indicates to the jackson library to escalate again of one level the json file so obtaining the `"1234"` string labelled by `"pin"`.The `JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME` compares the `"pin"` string with the names of subclasses and because of it fails causing the issue and the error message.